# Ducati Panigale V2 2021 stop eng

Tags: ducati

It is the first I have had an Italian Bike. After many years of Suzuki Race world, it is the first time I'm facing a motorcycle issue.

I have a Ducati Panigale V2 2021 white (I only mention it because a white bike is more expensive than the red one). It has about 1000km of use, I did the service at a Ducati dealer.

Now, just 300km later. Sometimes my bike stops the eng. It happened a few times. It happened after a small trip back home when I stop the bike in front of my garage gate. I put the bike on N to open the gate. Happened also in the red light.

Today I went to Ducati and that wasn't a surprise they didn't find any problem but they updated the software for me and wished me luck.

To me as a new Ducatista, when my bike is on N, it sounds like it needs a little more gas.

Fellas here, Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: check spark plug leads maybe ?

Comment: This appears to me as Ducati lacking expertise to figure out this intermittent problem. Perhaps searching for Ducati specialists outside of Ducati may reveal experienced people with advanced experience in these areas.